# Angular: Best way to do media queries

Tags: angular, media-queries, responsive

Currently I use NgZone to run media queries. I'm curious if this is the best way to do this.

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

const SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT = 840;

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private mediaMatcher: MediaQueryList = matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT}px)`);
  constructor (
    zone: NgZone,
  ) {
    this.mediaMatcher.addListener(mql => zone.run(() => this.mediaMatcher = mql));
  }

  isScreenSmall(): boolean {
    return this.mediaMatcher.matches;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is a very old question, but I came upon this while trying to do the same thing in our Angular 9 app.

What you've suggested looks like a pretty good way, although it can be done without using zone.run, if you want to import the zone.js webapis-media-query file into your app as well.

`import 'zone.js/dist/webapis-media-query'` [(see zone.js non standard apis)](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/zone.js/NON-STANDARD-APIS.md)

I ran into this issue when trying to use `matchMedia('...').addListener` to push the new breakpoint to a Rxjs Subject. I was subscribing to that subject in a Component, and it was not triggering change detection in the template when the value changed. The template took about 5 seconds to update (due to zone's periodic updates). Importing the `webapis-media-query` file resolved the issue for me.

If you do not need to support IE or Safari (at least 12.1.2 at time of writing), you can use `window.matchMedia('max-width: 648px').addEventListener('change', callback)` which zone.js does seem to patch without needing to import that library.

Our source:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/webapis-media-query'

interface BreakpointQuery {
  query: string,
  breakpoint: ScreenSize
}

type MediaQueryListListener = (event: MediaQueryListEvent) => void

export enum ScreenSize { Small, Medium, Large }

const SMALL = 640
const MEDIUM = 1024
const queries: BreakpointQuery[] = [
  { query: `(max-width: ${SMALL}px)`, breakpoint: ScreenSize.Small },
  { query: `(min-width: ${SMALL + 1}px) and (max-width: ${MEDIUM}px)`, breakpoint: ScreenSize.Medium },
  { query: `(min-width: ${MEDIUM + 1}px)`, breakpoint: ScreenSize.Large }
]

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScreenSizeService {
  size: Observable<ScreenSize>

  private subject: BehaviorSubject<ScreenSize>

  constructor (
    private readonly windowRefService: WindowRefService
  ) {
    this.setupSizeObservable()
    this.setupMediaQueries()
  }

  private setupSizeObservable (): void {
    this.subject = new BehaviorSubject<ScreenSize>(this.currentSize())
    this.size = this.subject.asObservable()
  }

  private setupMediaQueries (): void {
    queries.forEach(breakpointQuery => {
      // @see False deprecation of addListener https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32210
      this.windowRefService.matchMedia(breakpointQuery.query)
        .addListener(this.mediaChange(breakpointQuery.breakpoint))
    })
  }

  private mediaChange (size: ScreenSize): MediaQueryListListener {
    return (event: any) => {
      if (event.matches) {
        this.subject.next(size)
      }
    }
  }

  private currentSize (): ScreenSize {
    const current = queries.find(breakpointQuery => {
      return this.windowRefService.matchMedia(breakpointQuery.query).matches
    })
    return current!.breakpoint
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great service you've added @Benno. I am going to use this window.service https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-window-provider?file=app%2Fcore%2Fservices%2Fwindow.service.ts but also wanted to ask where you got the typings for `MediaQueryListListener`?

Comment: @BenRacicot we added it to our repos custom-typings as it was removed from typescript in 3.1 I believe. This is our type: `type MediaQueryListListener = (event: any) => void`
But I think we can actually use this now: `type MediaQueryListListener = (event: MediaQueryListEvent) => void`